# Mountpoint for mounted external partition owned by root

Tags: permissions, mount

So anytime a drive is mounted by a user or administrator using udisks2 over dbus, such as plugging in a drive and using any GUI application or file manager to mount it, the mountpoint that's created is owned by root and not accessible by the user who mounted it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was that when I create filesystems with mkfs.ext4, the program sets the ownership to root by default.